# Can javapackager generate just .app instead of .dmg?

Tags: java, macos, .app, javapackager

We are updating our Mac support from Java 1.6 to Java 1.8.
Part of this is switching to using javapackager to generate the .app bundle.  The problem is that it always puts the .app into a .dmg.  I need the .app separate so we can build our full installer.

Is there any way to convince javapackager to just generate the .app?

Answer (score 2):

Just use the option `-native image` (can be `all`—the default—, `image`, `installer`, or platform-specific installer formats, see Oracle's [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/javapackager.html)):

```
$ javapackager -deploy -native image -srcdir <src_dir> -outdir <out_dir> -outfile <out_file>
```

Answer (score 0):

There was a bug fixed in the Java Packager where "-native image" didn't work. I know this has been fixed for JDK 9 but I don't believe it has been backported yet. If you are using JDK 8, "-native" or "-native all" should generate all possible output, but it will take a bit longer.